# Google Data studio-Customised BarChart Tooltip

Tags: looker-studio

I have created bar chart using Google data studio. Now I have to add a dimension values(For each BookingCategory in chart we have different agents. So I want to display Agents with there booking count in each bar Tooltip) on the tooltip of the barchart. 
Is this Feasible to achieve ?

[image]

Comment: Could you elaborate by providing a publicly editable Google Data Studio Report (additionally, a Google Sheet if it's the data set) of the scenario (using sample data that shows 1) Input values (~10 rows) 2) Expected output 3) An attempt at solving the issue)? It would help users visualise the issue and test out suggestions on a specific use case with objective right / wrong answers. Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it would be difficult to pinpoint a suggestion and the issue, e.g. Data Set, Data Source, Report, Fields, Chart

Answer (score 0):

You can show bookings by agent in your bar chart by adding it as a secondary/breakdown dimensions and selected "stacked" in the style menu.
Hopefully I've understood your question correctly!